# ubuntu 12.10, likewise, and logging in to the domain

Tags: active-directory, likewise

Ok, so Ive successfully joined my new ubuntu 12.10 install to my office's domain but....BUT, I cant actually you know, log in! On previous versions of Ubuntu we had the ability to log in as "other" where we could log in using the UPN, but that option doesnt look like it exists in 12.10.

So uh, how do I log in?

Answer (score 2):

ok, think I got it :

just type in this command line :

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "greeter-show-manual-login=true" >> /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf'
```

and then reboot the computer and then you will have the ability to type in a user account, just type in DOMAIN\user